# Display the big text newline dynamically from database by using Dom

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with dynamic newline, in big text. I have using DOM to print the text, but, the text is too big and causes my website to look uglier than expected. Here is an example:

"Hi, my name is Ariff and I come from ..... and.... love......"

Desired Result:

"Hi, my name is Ariff
and i come from ..... 
and.................
love................"

All the text is coming from a database, so I'm unable to predict the size.

```
var textdetails = document.createElement("SPAN");
    textdetails.style.display = "block";
    textdetails.innerText =  shordetails;
    h3.appendChild(textdetails);
    document.getElementById('add-info').insertBefore(div, display.childNodes);
```

Comment: Look into the CSS [white-space property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Comment: Have you considered a CSS solution instead of inserting newlines using Javascript? After all CSS is all about the layout.